# where to load javascript in a view page Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .. right now i am loading my js and css files like this

**View/Layout/default.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('css'); ?>
<?php echo $this->fetch('script'); ?>
<?php echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom');?>
```

and in each view file i am doing this because there are some pages i am loading different css and js files

for example
   **View/users/index.ctp**

```
 echo $this->Html->script('libs/modernizr.custom',array('inline' => false));
  $this->Html->css('reset3860.css', null, array('inline' => false));
  echo $this->Html->script('libs/jquery-1.8.2.min', array('block' => 'scriptBottom'));
```

now the first problem i am facing right now is when i have to write **js** at the bottom of view page for example if i am submitting a form through ajax .. i can't write at the bottom of the index page ... because if i write there the js will go at the middle or center of the page so now what i do is i go the default.ctp and write there.. 
so i want to write at the bottom of the index page so it can easily managable and i can see it well what i am doing

the second question is what is the best way to manage all this ... or is there a way that i can make one file of cs and js ... in which there is only the **css** and **js** files are loaded ..and then i include that file in my default . ctp page

Answer (score 3):

You should place `scriptBottom` block at the bottom of your layout, after `content` block:

```
<body>
    <?php
    echo $this->fetch('script');
    echo $this->fetch('content');
    echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom');
    ?>
</body>
```

And then in your views (notice - NO `echo`):

```
$this->Html->script(
    'libs/jquery-1.8.2.min', 
    array('block' => 'scriptBottom')
);
$this->Html->scriptBlock(
    "alert('Boom!');",
    array('block' => 'scriptBottom')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is very good concept and also i have applied in one of my application, it is working very well

it compatible with CakePHP 2.1, and packaged it as a plugin. And also upgraded the CSS compression from CSSTidy to the more recent and better maintained CSS Min.

The plugin is quick and easy to install. The installation instructions are somewhat long - but that's just to provide clarity.

for detail view you can refer Detail link [Cakephp.org](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/joshua.paling/2012/05/19/combinator_plugin_combine_minify_and_cache_css_and_js_files_in_cakephp_2_1)  also you can see the plugin [document](https://github.com/joshuapaling/CakePHP-Combinator-Plugin) and how to use it in your appliation

Comment: well right now i dont want to use any plugin .. can you tell me the solution without any thirdparty plugins

Comment: but i could suggest you to use it, but you can also make in layout view file and render it in main view as elements,

Comment: well these thirdparty plugins make website slower thats y i dont want to use right now ..may be in future i will.. can you tell me how to use elements .. can u give me some example of it ... and please dont refer me to the documentation

Comment: sorry to say but i am not able to post whole answer, and put some efforts by your selft,dont be dependent on others just looks http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html

Comment: The asset compress plugin from mark story is better than the plugin you named here. https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress